# Google Automotive Services in system built from sources

Tags: google-play-services, android-automotive

I'm trying to build my own Android Automotive OS on Raspberry Pi. I've been stuck on Google Automotive (Play?) Services. When opening an emulator downloaded for Android Studio, everything is there - Google Maps as a navigation app, Google Account integration, etc. However, when building (an emulator or an image for my board) from sources, there is nothing. I'm looking for a way to add Google services to my image, to build from scratch on OS similar to one offered by Polestar/Volvo/GM.

Answer (score 0):

AAOS (Android Automotive OS) is open source code w/out Google specific services in it.

PTAL https://developers.google.com/cars for more detail for GAS.

> Car makers can also contract with Google to provide services such as
> Maps and the Google Assistant in their cars via Google Automotive
> Services (GAS).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is there no way to use Google Maps or log into own Google account on AAOS built from sources? How is it done in vendor companies like Volvo?

Comment: PTAL https://developers.google.com/cars

Comment: That leads me to two more questions. 1. If contacting Google is the only way to use Google services/apps - what is the procedure? There is no "contact us" button. I've tried to ask a similar question on Google Community, but there is no answer. 2. What is the difference between car_x86_64 and aosp_car_x86_64 build configurations? I can't find any documentation and comparing mk files is tricky.